# Get predicted values with model.predict using ImageDataGenerator - keras 2.1.0 (deep learning)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to get all correct and incorrect predicted values (I want predict class of images)

So, my code is:

```
#Load the trained model
loaded_model= tf.keras.models.load_model('C:/Desktop/data/model.h5')

#ImageDataGenerator for reading data from directory
test_generator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    'C:/Desktop/data/test',
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch,
    class_mode='categorical')

#Predicting the classes of images
predictions = loaded_model.predict(test_generator)
print('predictions shape:', predictions.shape)
print('predictions:', predictions)
```

Output for `predictions.shape` is `(568, 2)` and for `predictions`:

```
[[4.5327284e-11 1.0000000e+00]
 [1.0000000e+00 3.6808674e-11]
 [1.3124708e-03 9.9868757e-01]
 ...
 [1.0000000e+00 2.0863072e-11]
 [9.3747419e-01 6.2525854e-02]
 [1.0000000e+00 4.2702163e-14]]
```

But I need to get predictions like data which can be used to confusion matrix

[image]

So I need to have values like:

```
24 predictions for class 1 was correct
 5 predictions for class 1 was incorrect
 1 prediction for class 0 was correct
 7 predictions for class 0 was incorrect
```

## EDIT:

I am trying to use code from [tutorial](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-image-classification-with-keras-flow-from-directory-and-generators-95f75ebe5720) but I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'class_indicies'
```

My code now:

```
test_generator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Desktop/data/test',
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=False)

predictions = loaded_model.predict(test_generator, steps=test_generator.batch_size, verbose=1)
predicted_class_indices = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
print('predictions: ', predicted_class_indices)

labels = test_generator.class_indicies #here I am getting an error
labels = dict((v,k) for k,v in labels.items())
predictionss = [labels[k] for k in predicted_class_indices]
print(predictionss)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your shape, I'm assuming you have 2 classes.

```
#Load the trained model
loaded_model= tf.keras.models.load_model('C:/Desktop/data/model.h5')

#ImageDataGenerator for reading data from directory
test_generator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    'C:/Desktop/data/test',
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch,
    class_mode='categorical')

#Predicting the classes of images
predictions = loaded_model.predict_generator(test_generator)
print('predictions shape:', predictions.shape)
print('predictions:', predictions)

# getting the labels

pred_labels = list(np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1))

# getting true labels
true_labels = test_generator.classes

# get the confusion plot

cm = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(true_labels, pred_labels)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, but I am getting an error: `cm = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(true_labels, pred_labels)
AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'metrics'`

Comment: Does this work if you use load_weights rather than load_model?  I am able to call evaluate on the loaded model using load_weights but the predict_generator line causes an error: "'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_generator"